# Increase the width and height of the default Gutenberg 'search' block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am using the default `Search Block` that comes with the `Gutenberg`

[image]

Currently, it does not span the whole width of my web-page as shown below,

[image]

How can I increase the width of the search box to full page width? I do not see any settings provided. Can this be done using Custom CSS code?

I added `search-width` class to the block as shown below

```
.search-width{
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

The `font-size` attribute is working and the changes are reflected in the web-page but `width` seems to have no effect.
The link to the web-page is [here](https://www.travelthrive.com/try-blocks/).

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[image: screenshot of web page]

Hi! I had a look at your page in the browser. I can see that the .search-width class that you applied is on the parent 'form' element , which contains the search input and the button. The form was indeed 100% width but the input field also needed to have 100% width applied to make it take up that space. I tried applying a style tag containing"width:100%" to the input , and this didn't work, but then i tried taking out the class "wp-block-search__input". This made it work.

I'm not that familiar with blocks... that class would have to be changed or overridden.
There's also some margin to the right, not sure where that's coming from.
Hope this helps a little... if you'd like me to take a look at your gutenberg editor I 'd be glad to see if I can help further.

Comment: Thankyou for the clarification. It helps. Can you please describe to me in more detail how to do `but then i tried taking out the class "wp-block-search__input". This made it work.`? I am a novice in web-site development.

Comment: Also I understand your solution but it would be only for my local system. On refresh I think the change will be destroyed. How to do it permanently?

Comment: Yes that's right... I was experimenting in the browser, which is a good place to start to understand what is happening with the layout, so that you know what has to be done. If you are happy to share your login credentials with me I could take a look at your WP install

Comment: Thankyou so much for extending this, but it will be quite difficult to share the credentials as building for someone else.